# How to merge two objects in typescript?

Tags: javascript, object, typescript, object-literal, get-request

So I am making two get requests, one request returns:
`department: string[]`

and another get request returns an object of the following:

```js
globalObj: {
  count: number[],
  admin: {
    department: string,
    email: string,
    img_path: string,
    name: string
  }[]
}
```

I want to be able to merge these two objects so that I can get the following:

```js
departments: {
  dep_name: string,
  globalObj: {
    count: number[],
    admin: {
      department: string,
      email: string,
      img_path: string,
      name: string
    }[]
  }
}[];
```

Meaning for each department name, I get it corresponding `globalObj`.

I just don't know how to merge them.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are the values of globalObj.admin.department unique?

Comment: I assume the string in the `department` array returned by the first request ha values corresponding to `globalObj.admin.department`?

Comment: no they are not unique. @Paarth

Comment: Not necessarily @Paarth

Comment: How can I merge them? @Paarth

Comment: Well how does one correspond to the other? Let's say I have the first department and I have to find the globalObj admin entry that goes with it? Or does the same globalObj go with every department string?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit uncleat what you mean by

> I get corresponding globalObj

But if you need to merge array with the same globalObj, the following code will do the trick:

```
let globalObj = {
  count: [1,2,3],
  admin: [
    {
        department: 'a',
        email: 'b',
        img_path: 'c',
        name: 'd'
    }
  ]
}

let departmentNames = ["x", "y", "z"];

let merged = departmentNames.map((depName) =>
{
    return {
        dep_name: depName,
        globalObj: globalObj
    }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add key to the object.

just like this one below:

```
var firstResponse = {
    globalObj: {
        count: [],
        admin: {
            department: '',
            email: '',
            img_path: '',
            name: ''
        }
    }
}

var secondResponse = {
    dep_name: ''
}   

secondResponse.globalObj = firstResponse;
```

this should return an updated `secondResponse` json